# The cartesian product of two lebesgue measurable sets is still lebesgue measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This question has been asked for several times but I still can't find an answer, so how to prove this statement. my thought is that every lebesgue measurable set can be represented as the union of a sigma-finite set and a negligible set and what should I do next

Comment: No @HallaSurvivor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, the Lebesgue sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}^d$ is the completion of the Borel sigma algebra $B_{\mathbb{R}^d}$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $m$. For any $d \geq 0$, let $B_d$ denote the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and let $L_d$ denote it's completion, aka the Lebesgue sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}^d$. I will prove that $\{E \times F \colon E \in L_n, F \in L_m\} \subset L_{n + m}$.

Let $E \in L_n, F \in L_m$ be arbitrary. Since $E \in L_n$, there exist $B_1, N_1 \in B_n$ and a (possibly not Borel) subset $S_1 \subset N_1$ such that $m(N_1) = 0$ and $E = B_1 \cup S_1$. Similarly, we can write $F = B_2 \cup S_2$, with $B_2, N_2 \in B_m$, $S_2 \subset N_2$, and $m(N_2) = 0$. We have
$$E \times F = (B_1 \times B_2) \cup (B_1 \times S_2) \cup (S_1 \times B_2) \cup (S_1 \times S_2).$$
Recall the elementary result that if $X, Y$ are second countable topological spaces, then we have equality of the product sigma algebra and the Borel sigma algebra: $B_X \otimes B_Y = B_{X \times Y}$. Thus $B_n \otimes B_m = B_{n + m}$. In particular, $B_1 \times B_2, (B_1 \times N_2) \cup (N_1 \times B_2) \cup (N_1 \times N_2) \in B_{n + m}$. We have
$$(B_1 \times S_2) \cup (S_1 \times B_2) \cup (S_1 \times S_2) \subset (B_1 \times N_2) \cup (N_1 \times B_2) \cup (N_1 \times N_2)$$
and
\begin{align}
m((B_1 \times N_2) \cup (N_1 \times B_2) \cup (N_1 \times N_2)) &\leq m(B_1 \times N_2) + m(N_1 \times B_2) + m(N_1 \times N_2) \\
&= m(B_1)m(N_2) + m(N_1)m(B_2) + m(N_1)m(N_2) \\
&= 0 + 0 + 0 \\
&= 0.
\end{align}
Thus $E \times F \in L_{n + m}$.

Comment: Could you please tell me why $m((B_1 \times N_2) \cup (N_1 \times B_2) \cup (N_1 \times N_2)) = 0.$? thank you

Comment: @YuerWu I added the computation. I guess I am implicitly using the fact that the Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb{R}^{n + m}, B_{n + m})$ coincides with the product measure induced by the product of the spaces $(\mathbb{R}^n, B_n, m)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^m, B_m, m)$. This is true because both measures agree on sets of the form $I_1 \times I_2 \times ... \times I_{n + m}$ where each $I_j \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an interval.